# Why does the Heisenberg uncertainty principle work in an atom?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, energy, electrons

Where is my logic wrong?

An electron can only assume quantized energies in an atom.

If an electron is localized in space in a hydrogen atom, its radius is known. If its radius is known, its electrostatic potential energy is known. Then, if the electron assumes quantized energies, its kinetic energies are quantized by $E_\mathrm{total} - E_\mathrm{potential}$ for all quantized possible total energies of the electron. This gives us quantized kinetic energy and thus momentum, giving us quantized frequencies. If you sum all of the waves of those frequencies, will it give the localized position wave-function? They can't right due to the fact that they're quantized.

This is probably very wrong; I just don't understand how.

Comment: This doesn't work because you don't know the radius of the electron about the nucleus. When you see values of atomic radii, these are average values inferred from the distance between atoms in molecules or the spacing of ions in crystals. Electrons have a probability distribution of their position and this distribution doesn't have a max cutoff distance. Technically, the electron could be arbitrarily far away from the nucleus, though the probability for any significant distance is vanishingly small.

Comment: You are referring to the Bohr model of the atom, which was an early model that ultimately proved somewhat insufficient to describe reality.

Comment: Recall that the uncertainty principle only applies to knowing _at the same instant in time_ the position and momentum. So it is possible to measure the energy  (momentum squared/mass) exactly, but therefore, not where the electron is.

Comment: @Zhe "somewhat insufficient" means it is unable to reproduce anything quantum in nature, including Heisenberg uncertainty principle

Comment: @Greg Sorry, is that a suggestion for an edit?

Comment: If the Heisenberg Ubcertainty Principle didn't work for atoms, they and everything made of them, including us, would collapse into black holes.  And God didn't want that.

Comment: @Zhe Your comment, it is up to you. In the given context that model is completely incorrect from a conceptual point of view (due to its classical nature), which has lead the OP to incorrect assumptions and incorrect physical picture.

Answer (score 0):

**Electrons don't have a well-defined orbital radius even in a hydrogen atom**

An electron "orbiting" in a hydrogen atom does not have a well-defined position or even just a well-defined radius just because it has a well-defined energy.

The orbital is more like a 3D probability density function covering a cloudy space of a defined shape (spherical in the case of the lowest energy orbital but not of a *single* radius and extending with a finite probability from the nucleus to a vaguely defined boundary we often regard as the radius of the atom).

Different orbitals have different, increasingly complex, shapes defined by solutions of the Schrodinger equation. Heisenberg's uncertainly relationship limits our ability to define the location and momentum of the electron at the same time. The fuzzy probability clouds defined by Schrodinger's solutions are the best we can do.